# Is there a function in ios webview like setCacheMode in android webview?

Tags: ios, webview

What feature should I use to allow iOS Webview's web content to be cached only for in the expired time in the server's meta data? I can't find keywords.

In Android Webview I solved it with setCacheMode (default).

Comment: i cannot found configuration option. but i found this function. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1414956-reloadfromorigin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please WBWebKit instead of Webview.
it will give you access for cache setting using the following code:

```
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
```

Comment: Does ios webview have a setCacheMode function?

Comment: i think NO. webview or wkwebview natively not supported `setCacheMode` in property.

Comment: Do I have to delete cache files every time it is turned on programmatically?